# Does Laravel Queue prevent duplicate records inserted by concurrent requests?

Tags: php, laravel

We have a Laravel API with a MariaDB database where we are having the issue of duplicate records in the database that are created by concurrent requests.

We assumed that implementing a queue would solve this, by handling one request at a time. 
But we still have the same issue of duplicate records.

In the application we have a check that looks for duplicates, but of course that won't work for concurrent requests that will create the same record at the same time.

We are unable to use a unique constraint at database level, partially because of Laravel's soft delete mechanism, and partially because of complex business logic that should allow duplicates if the value of one of the fields matches a certain set of values.

We use Redis as the queue driver.

Are we wrong by thinking that the queue should prevent these issues? 
Or did we somehow made a mistake somewhere implementing the queue?

This is a simplified version of the controller:

```
class CreateRecordJob extends Job implements SelfHandling
{

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $data = $this->data;

        // check if we have this record in the database already
        if(!$this->hasDuplicate($data)) {
            $this->createRecord();
        }
    }
}
```

In config/queue.php we have set Redis as the default queue driver:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),
```

And also in config/queue.php we have this for the redis connection:

```
'redis' => [
    'driver'     => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
    'queue'      => 'default',
    'expire'     => 60,
],
```

Comment: Queue won't prevent two jobs with the same data to be created. Looks like `hasDuplicate` function does not do it's job properly. What I would suggest:

1. Check if `hasDuplicate` works correctly.

2. Do the check and inject as a transaction by adding `\DB::beginTransaction()` in the first line and `\DB::commit()` in the last line of the `handle()` method.

3. Making unique index on one or multiple of the fields in the database. This heavily depends on your logic.

Comment: db transactions on concurent requests can be a reason of deadlocks

Comment: @michail1982 only if applied incorrectly. Simple "check if exists and if not then insert" is a perfect case for transaction to maintain consistency. Otherwise you can check that record doesn't exists while the other process just created it. If it doesn't exists process number 1 will create it, creating a duplicate.

Comment: hasDuplicate works fine if the request comes in a second later. And unique indexes are not an option with the current business logic. @ChrisCynarski there is only 1 table involved in this, will a transaction help me out in this case?

Comment: @sunomad You should definitely give it a try. It's a perfect case for a transaction.

Comment: @ChrisCynarski then when should I roll back the transaction? Normally I use transaction when dealing with multiple tables, and rollback if saving to one of them fails. But in this case, the problem is it will save.

Comment: By default if it fails it will be rolled back. You don't need to do it manually unless it's a part of your logic. You only care about committing the transaction.

Comment: Well, I just tried it, wrapping it in a transaction is still creating duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

basicly - not
you may find implementation of FIFO-compatable queue-drivers 
laravel has interface Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Mutex  for this purposes, byt yuo need to extend queueManager to use it

Comment: If you have one worker the jobs are running one after another anyway. This won't help if the data in subsequent jobs is the same. I would look at `hasDuplicate` method if works properly, or a cause of duplicated data at first place.

Comment: you can start any numbers of workers,, but mutex works on 1 server =(

Comment: amazon sqs has "Message Deduplication ID"  thats could help

Answer (score 0):

Since version 8, Laravel supports the implementation of [Unique Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#unique-jobs)

```php
 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
 
class UpdateSearchIndex implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
   // ...


    /**
     * The product instance.
     *
     * @var \App\Product
     */
    public $product;
 
    /**
     * The number of seconds after which the job's unique lock will be released.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $uniqueFor = 3600;
 
    /**
     * The unique ID of the job.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function uniqueId()
    {
        return $this->product->id;
    }

}
```